# Server Sent Events Close Connection - Spring Boot

Tags: javascript, java, spring, spring-boot, server-sent-events

i have one question about SSEEmitter in Java Spring Boot.
I have following code to etablish connection between client and server in Java Spring Boot. I have set the timeout of the SseEmitter - object to max value of long.

Now following scenary occurrs: I close the tab in the browser and the sseemitter object on the server don't close. So many objects are on the server. This leads to memory issues.

```
@RequestMapping(value = "/subscribe", consumes = MediaType.ALL_VALUE)
    public SseEmitter subscribe() {
        System.out.println("SUBSCRIBE CALLED!");
        System.out.println(emitters.size());
        SseEmitter x = new SseEmitter(Long.MAX_VALUE);
        try {
            x.send(SseEmitter.event().name("INIT"));
        } catch (IOException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
        x.onCompletion(()->{
            System.out.println("ON COMPLETION CALLED!");
            emitters.remove(x);
        });
                
        x.onTimeout(()->{
            System.out.println("ON TIMEOUT CALLED!");
            emitters.remove(x);
        });
        emitters.add(x);
        return x;
    }
```

How can I say the client to close the object?
Kind regards

Comment: Did you manage to find the solution by any chance? I'm struggling with the same issue and would love to know whether detecting client's disconnection in SSE is even possible.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you are using "emitters" to send future updates. Try to complete the emitter and remove it from "emimtter" in the catch (IOException) block where you send the emitter update: